# Problem with the correction of series exercise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Well, I have a little problem with the correction of an exercise, I have to calculate :

$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+(-1)^{n+1}}{n+(-1)^n}x^n, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

So I have :

$$
S(x)=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} x^{2p} - 2\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p}}{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}x^{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{p}
$$

It's the same on the correction but my problem is after, they simplify this four sums like this :

$$
-1-x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n - \frac{2}{x}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2p+1}}{2p+1}+x\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2)^p}{p}
$$

And it maybe be ridiculous for you but I don't understand why :

$$
\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}x^{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{p}=x\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2)^p}{p}
$$

For me :

$$\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}x^{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{p} = x*\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \left((x^2)^p \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)
$$

Thank's before for your help !

Shadock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is to assume that the 2 latter terms yield the result you have trouble understanding. First, I believe there may be a little typo. Allow me to demonstrate. You state:

$$S(x)=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} x^{2p} - 2\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p}}{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}x^{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{p}$$

I am going to work with the **first** and **third** terms. Clearly

$$\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} x^{2p} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}x^{2p+1} = \sum_{p=2}^{\infty}x^{p}$$

Furthermore,

$$\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}x^{p} = -1 - x +\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}x^{p}$$

So we have combined the first and third terms together. Going back to our original expression,

$$S(x) =  -1 - x +\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}x^{p} - 2\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p}}{2p+1} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{p}$$
$$= -1 - x +\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}x^{p} -\frac{2}{x}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{2p+1} + x\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x^{2})^{p}}{p}. $$

So the only difference is in the limits of the result of the 3rd term (there lies the typo, I believe). Hope this helps! Be sure to exhaust all possibilities before coming to conclusions :) !

Comment: You are most welcome.